# OpenVPN use IPtables NAT without sending all traffic through VPN

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, iptables

I have a VPN connection between two servers that I want to use to allow one to connect to the other's ports and use IPtables Prerouting to make it accessible from the other server. I **do not** want any normal traffic to be send over the VPN (Web, Mail, Generic).

The command I am using for IPtables is

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d myserver.com -p tcp --dport 3240 -j DNAT --to-dest 10.8.0.8:3240
```

where `10.8.0.8` is a static IP for the server using OpenVPN.

My OPENVPN client conf is

```
client
nobind
dev tun
remote-cert-tls server

remote myserver.com 1194 udp
key-direction 1
redirect-gateway def1
```

The issue is that when I add the `redirect-gateway` option at the bottom, all normal internet traffic is being sent across the VPN, which is not what I want. When I remove it, I lose the ability to use IPTables NAT for that server, I am not sure why this is the case because I am still able to connect with `nc 10.8.0.8 3240`, but IPTables is unable to forward the connection and I cannot find a location to get error logs for this.